# Images not being served from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have just performed a fresh install of Rails 3.2. The default "Welcome aboard" page was served fine when testing with built in webserver, however when I switched to Passenger together with Apache the Rails logo stopped showing up.

The image is located in `/myapp/app/assets/images/rails.png` and is called from document as `assets/rails.png`. This return 404.

I have set 755 permission on `/myapp/app/assets` folder and have `Allow from all` in my virtual host configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've set production in my `/myapp/config/environment.rb` file.

Comment: have you compiled assets,and is your rails_env is production check our apache conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out in your `config/production.rb` that you have

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

and serving static assets is also enabled in your Apache and site configuration.